# Get a list of all playing sounds (on a Mac)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-audio, nssound

How could I access all active sound files so I can stop them. E.g Let's imagine we have a few youtube videos playing in the browser. I didn't initiate these sounds so I don't have a reference to them. What can I do to programmatically stop playback?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any simple way to do this. The closest you can probably get is muting all sound, period, including yours. Hell, the user themselves can't control the volume of individual processes. :(